# using linkedtemplate to retrieve password from Keyvault

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

After reading some article from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/managed-applications/key-vault-access) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-linked-templates) and looking at this [example](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-key-vault-use-dynamic-id)

I have tried to retrieve a password from KeyValut with LinkedTemplate.

To achieve this aim I have create such a Linked arm template **azuredeploy.json**:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vaultName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the keyvault that contains the secret."
      }
    },
    "secretName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the secret."
      }
    },
    "vaultResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the resource group that contains the keyvault."
      }
    },
    "vaultSubscription": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the subscription that contains the keyvault."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": 
  [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
      "name": "dynamicSecret",
      "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
      "properties": {
        "mode": "Incremental",
        "templateLink": {
          "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
          "uri": "https://arm0storage.blob.core.windows.net/linkedtemplate/azuredeploy.json?sp=r&st=2019-07-17T13:28:26Z&se=2019-07-16T21:28:26Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=xxxv%2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%2FHmg9Yxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D&sr=b"
        },
        "parameters": {
          "adminPassword": {
            "reference": {
              "keyVault": {
                "id": "[resourceId(parameters('vaultSubscription'), parameters('vaultResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]"
              },
              "secretName": "[parameters('secretName')]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "SQLPassword": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('dynamicSecret').outputs.value]"
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to validate this template, I get this error message:

```
Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameters 'adminPassword' in the parameters file are not valid; they are not present in the original template and can therefore not be provided at deployment time. The only supported parameters for this template are 'vaultName, secretName, vaultResourceGroupName, vaultSubscription'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy/#parameter-file for usage details.'.
```

and in my **azuredeploy.parameters.json** I have:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vaultName": {
      "value": "kvnamer"
    },
    "secretName": {
      "value": "ExamplePassword"
    },
    "vaultResourceGroupName": {
      "value": "rgname"
    }
  }
}
```

Do you have any Idea how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please check if your linked template has the parameter "adminPassword".  For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-secrets-with-dynamic-id). You also can refer to my JSON file.

1.Create azuredeploy.json

```
  {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vaultName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the keyvault that contains the secret."
      }
    },
    "secretName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the secret."
      }
    },
    "vaultResourceGroupName": {
      "type": "string",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the resource group that contains the keyvault."
      }
    },
    "vaultSubscription": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[subscription()]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "The name of the subscription that contains the keyvault."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [{
    "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
    "name": "linkedTemplate",
    "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
    "properties": {
      "mode": "incremental",
      "templateLink": {
        "uri": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/master/azure-resource-manager/keyvaultparameter/sqlserver.json",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
      },
      "parameters": {
        "adminPassword": {
          "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
              "id": "[resourceId(parameters('vaultSubscription'), parameters('vaultResourceGroupName'), 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('vaultName'))]"
            },
            "secretName": "[parameters('secretName')]" 
          }
        },
        "adminLogin": {
            "value": "jimtest"
        },
        "sqlServerName": {"value": "jimteste12378902"}
      }
    }
  }],
  "outputs": {
    "SQLPassword": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.value]"
    }
  }
}
```

2.Create azuredeploy.parameters.json

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vaultName": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "secretName": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "vaultResourceGroupName": {
      "value": ""
    },
    "vaultSubscription": {
      "value": ""
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The template, you're using in the nested deployment here:

"https://arm0storage.blob.core.windows.net/linkedtemplate/azuredeploy.json?sp=r&st=2019-07-17T13:28:26Z&se=2019-07-16T21:28:26Z&spr=https&sv=2018-03-28&sig=xxxv%2xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%2FHmg9Yxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx%3D&sr=b"

What does that template look like?  The error message you're getting says that it does not have a parameter in it, named "adminPassword" - but your nested deployment resource is trying to pass it in.

The output you have in the template above is called "SQLPassword", they aren't necessarily related, but I'm guessing since we can't see the template you're linking to.